# Updating a second dropdown after the first one has been chosen in javascript/php/html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need an example that can let me populate the 2nd,3rd,...,7th dropdown list (all same entries) after the 1st dropdown list has been selected. I have all the values stored in an array in PHP before the HTML head.

I've looked at some examples, and couldnt find a specific solution

For example: 
Let's say I have a warehouse full of franchisees and outlets under those aforementioned franchisees, I need to create order lists for 7 days ahead for that specific franchisee with n outlets. My solution was that the user/warehouse operator would pick a franchisee, then the 2nd (up to 7th) drop down list would have the outlets who are under that picked franchisee.

Thanks.

---

```
<?php
$productClass = new product();
$productClass->setProductList();

$franchiseeClass = new users();
$franchiseeClass->getAndSetAllFranchisees();
$franchiseeArray = $franchiseeClass->getUserList();

$operatorOutletClass = new users();
$operatorOutletClass->getAndSetUserByLevel("5");

?>

<html><head></head><body>

<div align="center">
    <form name="BBOFranchisee" method="post" action="?" onSubmit="return checkSubmit()">
        <table align="center" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Franchisee: 
                </td>
                <td colspan="8">
                    <select name="displayFranchisee" size="1" onChange="populateOutlet('findOutletByFranchisee.php?fid='+this.value)">
                        <option label="franchisees" value="0">--Choose Franchisee--</option> 
                        <?php 
                        for($i=0;$i<count($franchiseeArray);$i++)
                        { 
                            foreach($franchiseeArray[$i] as $key => $val)
                            {
                                echo "<option label=\"franchisees\" value=\"$key\">$val</option>\n";
                            }             
                        } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <?php for($j=0;$j<7;$j++) { ?>
                <td>
                    Outlet:
                    <select name="displayOutlet<?php echo $j; ?>" size="1">
                        <option label="outlets" value="0">&nbsp;</option> 
                    </select>
                </td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess the continuation is the javascript part.. i tried to look at the solution that http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/change-dropdown-list-options-values-from-database-with-ajax-and-php.html provides, but it wont work with multiple drop downs.

Comment: @ErmanBelegu ok, i will try

Comment: where is your `populateOutlet()` function defined? Also, is it a typo that you have `nChange="populateOutlet()"` instead of `onChange="populateOutlet()"`?

Comment: @Sean Oh yeah, sorry, typo.,.. and no.. i havent defined that in the js since after i saw the example on the website i mentioned above, i deduced that it wont work for multiple dropdown boxes efficiently

Comment: You could use that code, just add a loop when doing the `innerHTML` - `for (var i=0;i<7;i++){ document.getElementById('displayOutlet'+i).innerHTML=req.responseText; }`. You would also need to add the `id` to your `<select>` loop

Comment: @Sean ok kewl, let me try it... hmmm why didnt you put this in the answer part?

Comment: @Sean wait... how do i add id to my select loop from the php script? the returning value would be a long "<select id=1><option>..</option></select><select id=2>....</select>" isnt?

Comment: I have posted an answer clarifying what I was saying. The id needs to go in your 2nd-7th selects in your original code, not in the ajax returned code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use that javascript example, you need to add an id to your 2nd-7th selects - `id="displayOutlet<?php echo $j; ?>"`

```
<?php for($j=0;$j<7;$j++) { ?>
      <td>
          Outlet:
          <select name="displayOutlet<?php echo $j; ?>" id="displayOutlet<?php echo $j; ?>"size="1">
               <option label="outlets" value="0">&nbsp;</option> 
          </select>
      </td>
<?php } ?>
```

Then in your javascript code, you can add a loop for the 2nd-7th selects.

```
if(req.status == 200) { // which represents ok status 
    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
        document.getElementById('displayOutlet'+i).innerHTML=req.responseText;
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks man... yup, i got it to work after couple of tweakings